# Como não somar valores zerados - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

Tenho várias colunas e algumas delas é praticamente zeradas, tipo a cada 100 linhas tem um valor.
Estou somando essas colunas com SUM(coluna1), SUM(coluna2)... mas na hora de somar essas colunas eu não quero que pegue esses valores zerado, então deixei dessa forma:

```
Select 
    SUM(coluna1),
    SUM(coluna2),
    [...]
From tabela
Where 
    ano_mes = 202004 
    And ( coluna1 != 0
    Or  coluna2 != 0
    Or coluna3 != 0 
    Or coluna4 != 0 
    Or coluna5 != 0 
    Or coluna6 != 0 
    Or coluna7 != 0 )
```

Também já fiz com o Not In('0') para cada coluna, mas do mesmo jeito está aparecendo os valores zerados, o que acredito que esteja somando também, pegando mais tempo da consulta, como posso melhorar isso?

OBS: eu dei um exemplo sem conter os nomes das tabelas e colunas, pois não posso. Também é acompanhado por outras colunas que não estão somando, somente para identificar as informações dos valores.

Comment: Mas zero não é o elemento neutro na adição? Ele nunca interferirá no resultado.

Comment: Você com os `or` está tirando as linhas que tem pelo menos uma das colunas sem ser zero. Aí tipo, se numa linha coluna1 for um valor diferente de zero e todas as outras colunas forem zero a linha será considerada na sua query. É isso que você quer mesmo?

Comment: @JorgeMendes Vamos supor:

Linha 1 Coluna 1 = 2 / Coluna 2 = 0 / Coluna 3 = 0 / Coluna 4 = 1
Linha 1 Coluna 1 = 2 / Coluna 2 = 0 / Coluna 3 = 0 / Coluna 4 = 1

No resultado quero que ele traga todas as colunas com as informações e a soma da coluna 1 (4) e Coluna 4(2). Mas cada linha muda os valores de cada coluna, hoje demora 13mins para consulta realizar, preciso que demore no mínimo 7mins.

Comment: Se você quer "que demore no mínimo 7mins" e "hoje demora 13mins" então atende plenamente a seus requisitos.

Comment: Me parece que este é um problema xy. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy

Comment: @anonimo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456269/melhorar-perfomece-da-procedure-sql?noredirect=1#comment869873_456269 esse é meu problema

Comment: Olha, eu vi seu outro link e você precisa mesmo fazer a análise em tantos grupos ou você está usando o group by só para manter as colunas? Que se você só estiver fazendo o group_by por isso pode ser mais simples criar as somas em outra tabela e juntar as duas com um join.

Comment: Como falou o @anonimo sobre problema xy, acho útil você tentar procurar respostas sobre como chegar ao formato final que você quer e não sobre seu método específico. Pode fazer um edit comentando isso? Deixando claro como você quer que o resultado seja?

Comment: @TatianeLucia Você pode acrescentar informações sobre a tabela? Por exemplo, o que ela armazena, qual é a chave primária do índice *clustered*, como é o processo de inclusão de linhas na tabela, qual o número aproximado de linhas etc?   Acrescente essas informações lá no texto de sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPÇÃO 1**

O desempenho de sua consulta pode ser melhorado se houver índice com a coluna ano_mes como chave primária e contendo as colunas coluna1 a coluna7 e também as demais de identificação. Algo assim:

```
-- código #2 v2
CREATE nonclustered INDEX I2_tabela on tabela (ano_mes) include (coluna1, ..., coluna7, colunas_identificação);
```

Entretanto, é necessário ter cuidado com a criação a esmo de índices, principalmente quando a lista de colunas da cláusula INCLUDE é extensa. É que índices aumentam a carga de trabalho do SQL Server e também ocupam espaço físico. É um ganha-perde.

---

**OPÇÃO 2**

Outra opção é acrescentar coluna calculada na tabela

```
-- código #3
ALTER TABLE tabela
    add temValor as cast ( (sign(coluna1) + sign(coluna2) + sign(coluna3) + sign(coluna4) + sign(coluna5) + sign(coluna6) + sign(coluna7)) as tinyint) persisted;
```

e após criar o seguinte índice:

```
-- código #4 v2
CREATE nonclustered INDEX I2_tabela on tabela (ano_mes, temValor) include (coluna1, ..., coluna7, colunas_identificação);
```

Nas consultas basta então utilizar o seguinte predicado na cláusula WHERE

```
-- código #5 v2
SELECT colunas_identificação, ...
  from ...
  where ano_mes = 202004 
        and temValor > 0
  group by colunas_identificação;
```

Nesta opção a leitura também será eficiente e tem a vantagem de tornar a consulta SQL mais simples, em termos de escrita. Entretanto, é necessário ter cuidado com a criação a esmo de índices, principalmente quando a lista de colunas da cláusula INCLUDE é extensa. É que índices aumentam a carga de trabalho do SQL Server e também ocupam espaço físico. É um ganha-perde.

Esta opção considera que os valores das colunas coluna1 a coluna7 são sempre 0 ou valor positivo.

---

**OPÇÃO 3**

As duas opções acima são simples de implementar mas podem ter custo elevado em espaço físico. Como você cita que "*a cada 100 linhas tem um valor*", então o uso de índice filtrado pode ser uma forma de reduzir o espaço físico.

O código de criação do índice filtrado poderia ser algo como

```
-- código #6
CREATE nonclustered INDEX I2_tabela on tabela (ano_mes) include (coluna1, ..., coluna7)
     where (T.coluna1 <> 0 or ... or T.coluna7 <> 0);
```

Entretanto, não é possível utilizar o operador OR na cláusula WHERE para a criação de um índice filtrado. Também não é permitido utilizar coluna calculada. Mas há uma solução de contorno, que é adicionar a coluna temValor na tabela e utilizar procedimento de gatilho para atualizar o conteúdo dessa coluna.

```
-- código #7 v2
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD temValor tinyint default null;
go

CREATE TRIGGER ajusta_temValor on tabela
after INSERT, UPDATE as
UPDATE T
  set temvalor= case when (T.coluna1 <> 0 or ... or T.coluna7 <> 0) then 1 else 0 end
  from INSERTED as I
       inner join tabela as T on T.chave = I.chave;
go        

CREATE nonclustered INDEX I2_tabela on tabela (ano_mes) include (coluna1, ...coluna7, colunas_identificação)
     where temValor > 0;
go
```

Pronto!

A consulta SQL fica assim:

```
-- código #8 v2
SELECT colunas_identificação, sum(coluna1), ..., sum(coluna7)
  from tabela
  where ano_mes = 202004 and temValor > 0
  group by colunas_identificação;
```

---

**OPÇÃO 4**

É possível reduzir ainda mais o espaço físico ocupado pelo índice filtrado ao não incluir nele as colunas coluna1, ... coluna7.

```
-- código #9
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD temValor tinyint default null;
go

CREATE TRIGGER ajusta_temValor on tabela
after INSERT, UPDATE as
UPDATE T
  set temvalor= case when (T.coluna1 <> 0 or ... or T.coluna7 <> 0) then 1 else 0 end
  from INSERTED as I
       inner join tabela as T on T.chave = I.chave;
go        

CREATE nonclustered INDEX I2_tabela on tabela (ano_mes) 
     where temValor > 0;
go
```

Neste caso a consulta passa a ter a seguinte construção:

```
-- código #10
SELECT colunas_identificação, sum(coluna1), ..., sum(coluna7)
  from tabela with (index = I2_tabela)
  where ano_mes = 202004 and temValor > 0
  group by colunas_identificação;
```

Ao [analisar o plano de execução](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/11/21/o-plano-perfeito/) do código #10 percebe-se a presença do operador "Pesquisa de chave". Ou seja, ganha-se de um lado (menor espaço físico ocupado pelo índice) mas perde-se de outro (acesso adicional à tabela para obter o conteúdo das demais colunas).

---

**OBSERVAÇÕES**

As opções 1 e 2 resolvem de imediato o problema relatado mas têm um fator negativo: o espaço físico ocupado pelo novo índice. Em outro tópico você cita que são cerca de 50 milhões de linhas e que há 21 colunas a serem tratadas. Ou seja, será um índice que ocupará muito espaço físico, talvez próximo ao da tabela. Não me parecem boas opções.

A opção 3 talvez diminua o espaço físico ocupado pelo índice, se realmente for uma matriz esparsa. Para avaliar se compensa implementar a opção 3 deve-se antes avaliar quantas linhas serão indexadas.

A opção 4 também deve ser avaliada antes de ser implementada, tanto quanto ao espaço físico ocupado pelo novo índice quanto (e principalmente) ao aumento de leituras na tabela, por causa do operador "Pesquisa de chave".

Uma outra opção é avaliar se compensa particionar a tabela pela coluna ano_mes. Pode ser uma solução interessante, pois permitiria acessar diretamente o bloco de linha referente ao ano/mês desejado.

Também deve ser avaliada a possibilidade de alterar a chave primária do índice *clustered* para a coluna ano_mes e os impactos dessa alteração.

A possibilidade de uso de índice do tipo *columnstore* filtrado deve ser avaliada, caso a versão do SQL Server seja 2016 ou mais recente.

**Finalizando**, para propor soluções eficientes é necessário ter informações sobre o contexto. O que foi exposto sobre o caso está vago.

---

Converse com quem te passou a tarefa sobre as opções disponíveis.